# Do 1 of 3 different things with result of jQuery .filter()

Tags: jquery

I've got something like this. Depending on a flag, it will either remove OPTION elements for a SELECT list or disable those OPTION elements.

```
if (flg===0) {
   // do something
} else if (flg===1) {
   jQuery(...selection...).filter(function() {
      ... bunch of checks here : return true or false ...
   }).attr("disabled","disabled") ;
} else if (flg===2) {
   jQuery(...selection...).filter(function() {
      ... same bunch of checks here as for flg===1 : return true or false ...
   }).remove() ;
}
```

There's got to be an easier way. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
jQuery(...selection...).filter(function() {
   ... bunch of checks here : return true or false ...
}).function() {
   if (flg===1) { this.attr("disabled","disabled") ;}
   else if (flg===2) { this.remove() ; }  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the filtered items in a variable and then perform the operations based on the flag value:

```
let $filtered = jQuery(...selection...).filter(function() {
  // ...bunch of checks here: return true or false...
})

if (flg === 1) {
  $filtered.attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else if (flg === 2) {
  $filtered.remove();
}
```